# SLIME on the console

Tags: linux, emacs, lisp, slime

Does anyone have experience using SLIME on the console for Common Lisp? I'm trying to go through Practical Common Lisp but the commands in the book don't seem to work for the console version of emacs/SLIME. I suppose my question is: is there somewhere where I can find documentation specifically for SLIME on the console? Or if you have a suggestion for a completely different approach on the console, I'm all ears.

Comment: Can you include a copy/paste transcript from your terminal so we can see what is going wrong?  Which LISP are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean running slime with emacs on the console ie without X. Slime requires emacs (eq slime 'superior lisp interaction mode for emacs').

I ran it with emacs -nw (which just uses the terminal and no X facilities that I can see) and slime worked fine (Ubuntu 10.04 X86-64).

1. Are you running in emacs?
2. Is slime set up in your .emacs file?
3. Did you start slime via alt-X slim?

Tell us more about what you did and what you have set up and what output you get and we may be able to help more.